# filter character '!' not working angular js

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have a problem with my filter function in my Angular JS project. This is my code:

```html
<div class="tree-folder">
    <div ng-repeat="catalog in ListCatalogData | filter:TextSearchTree" ng-include="'treeItem'"></div>
</div>
```

It working very well with all character except '!'. I need help!

Answer (score 1):

In angular filter documentation:

> The string is used for matching against the contents of the array. All
>   strings or objects with string properties in array that match this
>   string will be returned. This also applies to nested object
>   properties. **The predicate can be negated by prefixing the string with**
>   **!**.

So if you have to search '!' you need write new filter like:

```
app.filter('wordsFilter', function() {
   return function(items, word) {
    var filtered = [];

    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        if(item.indexOf(word) !== -1){
            filtered.push(item);
        }
    });
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I think I will write new filter like your code. My tester team required me fix this bug now if I don't want to die :((